How do I reset the 'startDate' back to midnight for each iteration of the loop
I'm trying to create several recurring events starting after a set start date, based on a google spreadsheet. but it is adding the start time onto the previous event. How do I reset it to midnight after each iteration? thanks in advance
this is what i've currently got

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
 const startDate = new Date('September 1, 2024 00:00:00 AM GMT+0100');
 var endDate = new Date('08/10/2025');

function values() {
let range = spreadsheet.getRangeByName('sunday')

range.getValues().forEach(function(rows) {
var title = (rows[0])
const hours = (rows[1]*60)
const minutes = (rows[2]+hours)

    var startTime = new Date(startDate.setMinutes(minutes))
     Logger.log(title)
  
     Logger.log(startTime);
var startTime = new Date(startTime.setMinutes(0))
   });
 };
 


But this is what it is logging
9:37:11 PM Notice Execution started
9:37:13 PM Info test 1
9:37:13 PM Info Sun Sep 01 04:56:00 GMT+01:00 2024
9:37:13 PM Info test 2
9:37:13 PM Info Sun Sep 01 09:23:00 GMT+01:00 2024
9:37:13 PM Info test 3
9:37:13 PM Info Sun Sep 01 14:30:00 GMT+01:00 2024
9:37:13 PM Info test 4
9:37:13 PM Info Sun Sep 01 20:00:00 GMT+01:00 2024
9:37:13 PM Info test 5
9:37:13 PM Info Mon Sep 02 03:20:00 GMT+01:00 2024
9:37:14 PM Notice Execution completed


sorry, answered my own question. realised I needed to set the hours to 0 aswell as the minutes
var startTime = new Date (startDate.setHours(0))
var startTime = new Date (startDate.setMinutes(0))

